# Transform drop down to drop UP

Tags: html, css

I've been struggling with a bottom menu.

So : I have a menu in footer that have elements that show up when hovering, currently it goes down, but for reading purpose I'd like it to go up

I've tried several things (based on what I found in here for example) but I couldn't get it working

I made a jsfiddle to test things and show you what's up : http://jsfiddle.net/xyasu950/2/

I know I have to use

`bottom:100%;
 position:absolute;`

Any clue fellows ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated your [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xyasu950/3/). I think you want this.

```css
#footer .button {
  position: relative;
}
#footer .submenu {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FF0000;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  max-height: 0;
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out 0s;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out 0s;
  a {
    padding: 8px 10px;
    min-width: 220px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: initial;
  }
}
#footer .submenu li {
  position: relative
}
#footer > .submenu > ul {
  bottom: 0%;
  transition: bottom 0.1s;
}
#footer .submenu:hover {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
}
#footer .button:hover > .submenu {
  max-height: 300px;
  bottom: 100%
}
#social-top .submenu li {
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.7em;
}
```

```html
<footer id="footer" style="margin-left:50px;">
  <div class="button">
    <div style="margin-top:50px;">Hover me</div>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="">Hey</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Amazing mate ! It seems not so complicated but i was lost on what to target, glad you cleared that out!

Thank you so much

Comment: Hey ! Do you have any idea on how to reverse animation ?